# Excel VBA: Finding last row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the last row of a set of numbers for each column, however it seems my code is using the same last row as the previous column's last row.

Here is the first column's code:

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
xTitleId = "Select Total Sales cell"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
WorkRng.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A65") = "Total Sales"
Range("A66").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Set WorkRng = Range("A66")
```

Here is the adjacent column's code:

```
Dim WorkRng2 As Range
xTitleId2 = "Select Collected Range"
Set WorkRng2 = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId2, WorkRng2.Address, Type:=8)
WorkRng2.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B65") = "Collected Range"
Range("B66").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B66:B100").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B66").Select
Dim LastRow2 As Long
LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & LastRow2).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=SUM(B66:B" & LastRow2 & ")"
Range("B" & LastRow2).Offset(1, 0).Select
Set WorkRng2 = Range("B" & LastRow2).Offset(1, 0)
```

It keeps saying that LastRow2 is 66, however I would like it to be dynamic and independent of the first column's last row.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`. You have 1 (Column A) instead of 2.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a VBA Function like the below:

```
    Function GetLastRow(wsTarget As Worksheet, iCol)
    'Gets the last non-blank cell
    Dim lrow As Long, Max_Row

    Max_Row = 1048576
        On Error GoTo SmallFile

    TryAgain:
        With wsTarget
            lrow = .Cells(Max_Row, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        GetLastRow = lrow

        Exit Function
    SmallFile:
        Max_Row = 65536
        On Error GoTo 0
        GoTo TryAgain

    End Function
```

Then you specificy the worksheet and column number you're after. i.e. GetLastRow(worksheets("Sheet1"),1) would return the last row for Column A in the Sheet1 tab.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the fact, that xlUp gets last **visible** row, which can cause problems, if filters are present. Therefore, if filters might be active, use rather:

```
Function getLastRow(col As String, ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Call removeFilters(ws)
    getLastRow = ws.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Function

Sub removeFilters(ws As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

example of use:

```
dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("B1:B" & getLastRow("B", ActiveWorksheet))
```